# AFTNetworking no iOS 8.1.1 está com problemas?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Desenvolvi recentemente um app que usa AFTNetworking 2.0 e fiz testes no meu aparelho fisico usando iPhone 4S iOS 8.0. Porém os clientes que estão com o iOS 8.1.1 não conseguem fazer o envio dos dados de um cadastro.

Infelizmente não tenho um aparelho com iOS 8.1.1 e não pretendo atualizar o meu iPhone por motivos de futuros testes.

O app não encerra e nem trava, mas não só não envia o formulário.

O mais estranho que funciona normalmente nos emuladores, e já foi até aprovado pela Apple e ja está disponível na Apple Store.

E existe uma alerta para sucesso, e para falha na operação do AFNetworking.

Alguém teve o mesmo problema?

Código utilizado:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    // Importante
    AFJSONResponseSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [serializer setReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:serializer];
     manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
     manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 120;
    // Importante

    [manager GET:urlStrin parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // do whatever you'd like here; for example, if you want to convert
        // it to a string and log it, you might do something like:

        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



        if ([string isEqual: @"SENHA_NAO_CONFERE"]) {

            // Caso ocorra um erro e nao consiga salvar primeiro no webservice, ele também não salvará no banco local
            //return NO;
            app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            [self alertaVerificarSenha];
            flagVerdadeFalso = [self retornaFalso];


        }else{

            [self insereDadosAdvogadoBanco];

            [self alertadeSucesso];

            // 4 - Chama a tela com a lista de
            TelaPrevisualizacaoProcessoViewController*telaPrevisualizacao= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"telaPrevisualizacao"];

            [self presentViewController: telaPrevisualizacao animated: YES completion: nil];


            app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            flagVerdadeFalso = [self retornVerdade];

        app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
       }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: Qual método em específico você está usando @Tiago Amaral ? Aqui estou usando o AFNetwork no iOS `8.0`, `8.1`, `8.1.1` e `8.2` sem problemas.

Comment: Pergunta editada! Coloquei o codigo fonte usado.

Comment: O mais estranho é que o app não trava, não da mensagem de erro, e não é encerrado. Ele continua executando normal, e o user consegue navegar nele como se nada estivesse errado. Infelizmente não disponho de uma iPhone 5/6 para realizar os testes no Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiago,

De início quero dizer que uso o AFNetworking e está funcionando perfeitamente.

Em seguida, tenho algumas dúvidas quanto à teu problema:

1 - Estás enviando, e não imprime nada (erro) no log?
2 - Estás enviando um form com GET e sem parâmetros?

Enfim, segue abaixo a forma que utilizo a lib em meu projeto:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
```

Se a consulta for à uma API que utilize o OAUTH2, adicione a linha abaixo para validar a consulta:

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                                         @"TIPO_TOKEN",
                                         @"SEU_TOKEN"]
                     forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Se o tipo de envio (POST, somente para este) do formulário for JSON adicione a linha abaixo:

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
```

Para envios com POST:

```
[manager POST:strUrlRequest parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [error description]);
}];
```

Para consultas com GET:

```
[manager GET:strUrlRequest parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraço.

Comment: Eu nao tinha como fazer o Debug pois o erro so acontecia com o iPhone 5 e 6. E naotenho estes aparelhos nas maos para testas. Quem testou foi o coiente. E ele mora em outro estado. Entao removi o uso o AFTNetworking.